# Getting a specific value of data.table using a variable in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am wanting to us a specific value of a data.table.  The column names and amount of columns are always changing, so I cannot use :

```
df$column_5[2]
```

Or :

```
df[2,5]
```

To get value I need.

I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
x <- 5
df[2,x]
```

But I get an error saying:

> df[2,x]
>       Error in `[.data.table`(df, 2, x) : 
>       j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'x' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..x]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1."

Do you have any solutions to this issue?

Comment: You are using a `data.table` (i.e. not a dataframe)! Do you want a data.table-operation or a dataframe-operation?

Comment: Try `df[2, x, with = FALSE]`

Comment: @jogo My apologies for using the incorrect word.  Do you have a solution to my question?  Keep in mine I am still relatively new to R.

Comment: @Philip Always put the information about used packages in your question. Indexing of data.table is not the same as for dataframes.

Comment: @Mako212 Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!

Comment: When you're working with the `data.table` library, it changes how brackets behave with objects of class `data.table`. If you want to take advantage of R's standard `data.frame` evaluation of brackets, you need to specify `with = F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @jogo's comment, you're using a `data.table`.

The solution is in the error:

> Perhaps you intended DT[, ..x]

`df[2, ..x]` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! This and the solution from @Mako212 worked for me.

Comment: Like I said in a comment above, since I am still relatively new to R, I'm not the best at figuring out error messages.  Once I saw your solution, I caught it.

Comment: No problem, everyone starts somewhere. `data.table` objects extend `data.frame`, so your confusion isn't unreasonable. That said they differ in some important ways. If you have time [this faq](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#beginner-faqs) may be worth a read!

Comment: I guess this returns a sub-table. In case the value is desired, there's `DT[[x]][2]`, which also works with data frames.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll definitely take the time to go over this!